# How the code is impacting over data attribute values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, proc

I am new to Ruby on Rails.I got a project in Ruby on Rails to work on in which I am stuck with a problem. In this, I am creating a pipeline which has following values after the pipeline is created.

```
"values":[{"id":353248957,"job_id":30728378,"job_parameter_id"
:386,"data":"Arabidopsis thaliana\r"}
```

This is the JSON response returned by the pipeline creation ajax call. Somehow the data attribute is set the default in the code anywhere. I have written the code to add data manually which is as following

```
@JobDefaultParametersLoop=ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("query to get data from database")
      for @JobDefaultParameters in @JobDefaultParametersLoop
        @JobParameter=JobValue.new ({data: @JobDefaultParameters["data"],job_id:@job_to_save.id,parameter_id:@JobDefaultParameters["id"]})
        @JobParameter.save
        test.push(@JobDefaultParameters["data"])
      end
```

In this code `@JobDefaultParameters["data"]` sets the data attribute to the specified one but if I replace it using "test" then It still takes "Arabidopsis thaliana" as data. I have spent hours in finding this out that from where it is getting default values. There is no controller mentioned in the project to set these job_values but there is code in serializer which impacts `job_creation_method` method which is setting these attributes to save. It is as below

```
def values
object.values.changeable
```

end
and another code I think which may impact is in the model file.

```
scope :changeable, lambda{
joins(:parameter).where(parameters: { hidden: false, constant: false })
```

}

The other thing that I've noticed is `@JobDefaultParameters["data"]` contains a list of parameters but the data attribute takes only one. Please help me if I am badly stuck :( . Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: insufficient information although check any callback `after_save or something`.which set a value forecefully . or use changes or previous_chnages to check all changes of the field see here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

Comment: Actually that wasnt done using lambda, I got that later that there was a function in model file. Thanks for your response :)